# Strongly closed but not weakly closed convex subset.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach Space. Then, for the convex subsets $S$  of $X$ a familiar result is that $S$ is weakly closed if and only if it is strongly closed. This prelim exercise is to show that if $Y\subsetneq X^*,$ and $Y$ is a subspace of $X^*$ that separates points, then the result fails if we use the weak topology on $X$ induced by $Y.$ The hint is: consider an arbitrary $0\neq f\in X^*\setminus Y.$ I'd like feedback on my attempt.

The functionals in $Y$ induce a (weak) topology on $X$, which we write $\tau_{w_Y},$  for which the continuous linear functionals are precisely the members of $Y.$ Let $f$ be as above. Then, $\ker f$ is strongly closed. Suppose it is also closed in $\tau_{w_Y}.$ There is an $x_0\notin \ker f,$ and a $\phi\in Y$ such that $\phi (x_0)<\inf_{x\in \ker f}\phi (x).$ If $\phi $ vanishes on $\ker f$ then in fact, $\phi =cf$ for some $c\in \mathbb R\Rightarrow f\in Y,$ which is a contradiction. Otherwise, there is a $y\in \ker f$ such that $\phi (y)\neq 0$. Wlog $\phi(y)>0.$ As $\ker f$ is a vector subspace of $X$ we must have $-ny\in \ker f$ for all integers $n$. But then, $\phi(x_0)<-n\phi(y)$ for all integers $n$, and again, we get a contradiction.

Comment: No, I mean the weak topology on $X$ induced by the functionals in $Y$. That is, instead of using all the functionals in $X^*$ we use only the ones in $Y$ and the only condition on $Y$ is that it is a proper subset of $X^*$ and that it separates points, which I think is necessary to apply the Hahn- Banach separation theorem .

Comment: What is $\inf_{x\in\ker f}\phi(x)$ supposed to mean? If the space is complex (which it usually is in functional analysis), then this makes no sense. So, I guess you work with real spaces. Fine. But then your infimum is $-\infty$ unless $\phi|_{ker f}=0$. Why? Well, if $x\in\ker f$ such that $\phi(x)\neq 0$, then $\phi(\mathbb R x) = \mathbb R$.

Comment: This is what I proved, that the inf is -$\infty.$ The prelim exercise was apparently  taken from Royden's Real Analysis, and the scalars he considers are the reals. But even if we use $\mathbb C$ doesn't the result still follow because then we would have Re$\phi (x_0)<$Re$ \left \{ \phi (x):x\in \ker f \right \}.$

Comment: Your idea is fine, but your choice of $\phi$ is somewhat flawed because the infimum doesn't exist (as $\phi\neq f$). You should use the weak topology induced by $Y$ (that is, by the seminorms defined by the functionals in $Y$).

Comment: Isn't the fact that no such $\phi$ exists exactly what we want? I am applying the Separation Thm using the weak topology on $X$ induced $by \ Y$ which is valid because $Y$ separates points.  In this topology, the only continuous linear functionals on $X$ are the elements of $Y$ so $\phi$ in fact must be in $Y.$  Or what am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I don't know this separation theorem. Does that involve this infimum?

Comment: Rudin has the proof of a more general result which is the existence of $c$ s.t.  Re$\phi (x_0)<c$<Re$\left \{ \phi (x):x\in \ker f \right \}$ then infing over the RHS matches the inequality I used for the real scalars.

Comment: Ok, then your proof seems fine. You should've mentioned there though that you use this separation theorem. So, in Rudin what you have is (I guess) a closed convex set $C$, a point $x_0\notin C$ and a set $Y\in X^*$ separating points and the result is that there exists $\phi\in Y$ such that $Re\,\phi(x_0) < c < Re\,\phi(x)$ for all $x\in C$? BTW, you should have $Y\subsetneq X^*\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Oh, if $Y$ is not a subspace, your proof is not correct.

Comment: Yes $Y$ is given as a subspace.

Comment: Apart from the necessity to take real parts when we're dealing with a complex vector space, it's correct. But since you mentioned Rudin in the comments, it would be shorter to just use theorems 1.18 and 3.10.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Since $f$ is not continuous with respect to $\tau_{w_Y}$, then $\ker f$ can not be closed in $\tau_{w_Y}$ either.